# Failed to connect to Content Server

Tags: oracle, connection

So I've just Install Site Studio Designer and I want to connect to the web site.
I enter my Server Cgi URL (https://myservername:port/cs/idcplg).
When I click connect I got a Error :

> Failed to connect to Content Server "https://myservername/cs/idcplg" (Unable to open connection).

So I wonder wants wrong with my URL.The error log doesn't say much. And I don't think it'a a security issue. Do I miswritten it or do I suppose to put somthing else in the URL? Every docs and forums I've visted says it's the correct way. Could it be a network configuration issue.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

check if your services are up and running.

```
start--> Run--> services.msc--> (select your respective service.. eg:admin)--> start
```